# How to change the Windows folder path the Windows 7 boots from?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot

I have dual-booted my laptop with Windows 7, one in **C:** drive and other in **F:** drive. I had a problem running my Windows in **F:** drive. I reinstalled it, but it got installed in `F:\Windows\Windows\`. My boot entry still points to `F:\Windows`.

Can I change the boot path to `F:\Windows\Windows\`? If yes, how?

Or, what if I copy/move everything from `F:\Windows\Windows\` to `F:\Windows\`, replacing older files, which belong to the previous faulted Windows installation? And leave the boot path as `F:\Windows`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use your Windows 7 DVD or USB for installation. Do not install while logged in a Windows 7 system to keep installations independent from each other.
2. Use primary partition for installation. (Consider installing to VHD !)
3. Download and install [Windows 7 Boot Configuration Data (BCD) Editor](http://www.boyans.net) for managing Windows boot entries. The tool allows full editing of Windows 7 BCD store, you can change every single item - in your case paths, drives.

It comes with a "Dual-boot Repair" tool to help solve dual or multi boot issues automatically in one click.